# Regex match a string that can contain only characters and numbers

Tags: regex, spring, request-mapping

I'm working on Spring `@RequestMapping`

Let's say I have an URI : `/test/{param: REGEX}/something`,
or just `/test/REGEX/something` for non-spring folks.

The REGEX part is where I want to capture any string that can contain only letters and numbers. No special characters, no whitespaces.
For instance :

```
valid -> test/My1Self123/something
valid -> test/1MySelf123/something
valid -> test/MySe12Lf34/something
invalid -> test/_Mys1Elf/something
invalid -> test/!_ Myself/something
```

How would that expression look?
I've tried many combinations on regexr and regex101, but it didn't get me exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried?

Comment: I might have actually figured it out. I've tried variations of \/(\w+|\d+)\/ and it looks like the reason my testing wasn't working is because I forgot to include the / characters :/

Comment: Probably `[A-Za-z0-9]+` is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this should match only numbers and chars:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z]+
```

in Regex.

Comment: Yeah this is also one variant solution. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, but I figured it out.

```
\/(\w+|\d+)\/
```

This solved it for me, because I forgot to include `\/ \/` on online regex testers, and it matched many groups which I didn't want.
edit: Ended up using the answer above mine.

Comment: Don't use `\w` if you don't want to match underscores. Your proposed solution matches `test/_Mys1Elf/something` which you said should be invalid.

Comment: Oh, yeah I noticed after a while. I used the answer above. :)